# jira script runner script that counts 2 statuses or fields togheter

Tags: jira, custom-fields

i want to count how many issues are in status open, and in verify (our custom flow) per day.

if today 3 issues entered into status open, and 3 entered into status verify  i would like to see the result of that field saying 6.

now sure how the script should be done in SCRIPT RUNNER.

thanks guys =)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could tell what you want to solve. JIRA allows you to define filters, that will give all the time as result a list of issues found. You can then define / use reports and / or gadgets on dashboards to display the data based on those filters.

So a solution could be:

- Define a filter that searches for the issues. Something like `project = XYZ AND status in (open, verify)`.
- Save that filter under a name (e.g. "Open and verified").
- Use that filter then in a gadget that displays the issues as chart, ...

Comment: i want to be able to count how many issues are in certain status and add that number to the count of other status,        i want to know how many i have entering into status in progress + entering to status close.  if i have 2 entering in progress and 8 entering into close i want to return 10

Comment: Sorry, that is no requirement. As I have just mentioned, JQL will not help you here, because it returns all the time a list of issues. You may look at that, and see that 10 matched, so you have your number. Where will that number be included? Depending on your requirements, the answer will be completely different ...